# how to create a dictionary nested in python which will denote the number of occurences of a word associated with a particular work?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a  list like :-

```
new_list=[['happy', 'people', 'need', 'rest'], ['rest', 'apple', 'good', 'happy'],['kepler', 'people', 'happy', 'apple'],['need', 'good', 'happy', 'good']]
```

and another list like

```
a=['good', 'apple', 'people', 'rest', 'kepler', 'need', 'happy']
```

which contains the number of distinct words of the new_list given.
Now i want to iterate through each element in list 'a' and find the sublists in new_list that contain that element and then in those sublists I want to calculate the occurance of words in it. For example for word "good" in list "a" the sublists in new_list containing "good" are

```
[['rest', 'apple', 'good', 'happy'],['need', 'good', 'happy', 'good']]
```

now calculating the occurance of earch word in this list

```
{"good":{"rest":1,"apple":1,"happy":2,"need":1}}
```

similarly I want the overall output for all the elements in 'a' list. How to do tht ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `for`s and `if`s.

```
new_list=[['happy', 'people', 'need', 'rest'], ['rest', 'apple', 'good', 'happy'],['kepler', 'people', 'happy', 'apple'],['need', 'good', 'happy', 'good']]
a=['good', 'apple', 'people', 'rest', 'kepler', 'need', 'happy']

dct = {}
for item in a:
    mid_dct = {}
    for lst in new_list:
        if item in lst: #checks if distinct item is in list
            for word in lst: #iterates over that list to store words and their number of occurences
                if word != item:
                    if word in mid_dct: #if that word in dct, adds one, if not adds that to list
                        mid_dct[word] += 1
                    else:
                        mid_dct[word] = 1
    dct[item] = mid_dct        
print dct
```